# Laravel 8 Socialite check login

Tags: laravel, validation, authentication, laravel-socialite

is there a way to check if the user has logged in with a Socialite?
because i want to create a post based on this authentication.

what i have done

```
if (!empty(Socialite::driver('linkedin')->stateless()->user()))
        {
            $linkedinuser = Socialite::driver('linkedin')->stateless()->user();
            dd($linkedinuser);
        }

        return redirect('/profile/');
```

i expect to get the dump if user has authenticated with linkedin, or else return profile. Instead, i get an error

```
GuzzleHttp\Exception\ClientException
Client error: `POST https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/accessToken` resulted in a `400 Bad Request` response: {"error":"invalid_request","error_description":"A required parameter \"code\" is missing"}
```

how can this be checked ? thanks.

Comment: Give us more details about the case. Do you redirect the user to Linkedin first and then linkedin redirect him to your laravel route ? https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/socialite#routing

Comment: @EmilGeorgiev no, the user may or may not be redirected first. they also could have been logen in without socialite.so i want to perform some actions when user has loged in with socialite linkedin. thats y i need this checking condition.